# Can I add script in header using angluar's platform-browser

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-fullstack

I want to add script dynamically in the angular project, can I add a script in the header using angular's "@angular/platform-browser" library.
If yes then how to do this task? how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this the answer you're looking for but you can dynamically add a script to the header in angular, here's an example of how to do it in a service...

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SimpleService {

    constructor(
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private doc
    ) { }

    addScript() {
        //Add script tag
        let scriptTag = this.doc.createElement('script');

        //Set attributes
        scriptTag.setAttribute('src', 'your source');

        //Add script to header
        this.doc.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, This is one of the solutions to adding a script in the header tag in the angular project. but problem is that occurred when I want to replace it with the other script. here I want to explain the scenario which I am facing. I have 2 components of the angular project, that is component-1 and component-2. and script which will add in the header that comes from the backend. when component-1 will load, script-1 will be loaded in this component's header and as soon as component-2 will load, script-1 will be remove and script-2 will be add in this component's header

Comment: @Ashish please can you explain your problem more clearly in the question and provide some code - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is the common code to add script in header section this code is common for add component. but problem is that when one component gets loaded, script also loaded for that component but when second component does load, the previous script is not removing now two script is present for this component.  `setHeaderScript(headerScript: any) {
    let script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
    script.id = `schemaScript`;
    script.type = `application/ld+json`;
    script.text = `${headerScript}`;
    this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.head, script);
  }`